# Fuelphp Navigation bar with NavBuilder

Tags: navigation, fuelphp

I am fairly new to FuelPHP and I am trying to get a navigation bar at the top of my template. The database containing the menustructure is allready available.

**I found this nice looking class on GitHub:**

https://github.com/KrisOzolins/NavBuilder/blob/master/navbuilder.php

I am trying to get it working by adding the navbuilder.php file to my class directory: fuel/app/classes

And entered the example code from the https://github.com/KrisOzolins/NavBuilder instructions to my fuel/views/welcome/index.php file:

```
$menu = NavBuilder::factory()->build()->render();
echo $menu;
```

Before that I altered the $default_setting of the tablesetup in the class to reflect my database table.

**This is what I got:**

```
ErrorException [ Fatal Error ]:
Call to a member function render() on a non-object
```

As I told, I am fairly new to FuelPHP. I am also grasping the MVC approach for the first time.

Answer (score 0):

A quick look at the code shows that build() returns NULL instead of an instance of NavBuilder when the DB query to fetch the links doesn't produce a result.

So do this to mitigate:

```
$menu = NavBuilder::factory()->build();
if ($menu)
{
    echo $menu->render();
}
```